# Where can I ask questions about Ubiquiti Unifi devices?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask the following.

> **Are Ubiquiti Unifi devices enterprise-grade?**
>
> I have seen comments on stack such as
>
> > Unifi/Ubiquiti are not enterprise-grade devices and don’t offer optional paid support
>
> Most of the IT professionals I talk to would *and have* deployed Unifi kit professionally in the enterprise. What makes some feel that these devices are not enterprise grade?

Whenever I have mentioned anything to do with Ubiquiti on Super User, DIY or network engineering, my questions are immediately closed as "off topic" and I get numerous downvotes. This is a bit unfair IMO, particularly since both SU and NE have Unifi tags.

Where on SE *can* I ask questions about Ubiquiti devices?

For context, I am an IT guy who is deploying Ubiquiti devices professionally.

Comment: Without specific examples of these questions, on SU, it's difficult to explain the reason the questions are being closed as out of scope.  According to your profile, you have no questions that have been closed.  Strictly speaking, questions about Ubiquiti deployment in a professional setting should be within the scope of Network Engineering.  Can you provide examples here on Super User, since this is Meta Super User, and perhaps an answer can be provided?  We can't explain why questions on DIY or Network Engineering were closed.

Comment: @Ramhound I deleted the questions as they were flagged as off topic. Regarding specific examples, would the one I mentioned here be permissible on SU?

Comment: It is just a little frustrating that SU closes my questions as off-topic and tells me to post on NE, then NE closes my questions as off-topic and tells me to post on SU...

Comment: Screenshots of those questions would help understand what Is happening.  Links to the questions so those who can see the question, can look for themselves, but your lastest Ubiquiti [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1674082/how-do-you-turn-on-the-unifi-floodlight-for-people-only) provides some insight into the problem.  Outside of being able to use the existing functionality that exists, asking for a Python script to do what you want, is probably one reason that question will be migrated or closed. I haven't even said they are within scope at NE at this point, I said they should be.

Comment: Unless you link to those questions, I cannot speak to why those questions are being closed, since you deleted those questions instead of improving them and getting them reopened.

Comment: I assume you have abandoned the desire to get those questions reopened

Comment: I think this meta question conflating 2 different issues: 1) whether questions about Ubiquity Unifi devices in general are on-topic or not, and 2) whether this specific question you want to ask is on-topic or not. Looking at the existence of the tag and that the visible questions are not closed, looks like the answer to 1) is, yes, it's on-topic. However, the 2)nd question looks like something that might incite opinions/debates rather than facts, and is highly possibly off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I ask questions about Ubiquiti Unifi devices?

Wherever that they accept questions about managed switches, routers and access points. Now, the question you put as example, is not a good question because whenever or not you can ask a question is a two part test: is the question on topic and it's an acceptable question.

Not all questions about anything are questions that should be asked here. For example: what would MS do with Windows 11 that I should look forward? This question is about Windows, yes, but it's speculative in nature. Same as yours, it is trying to gather opinions on what features a certain product fulfills, which is explained in the [don't ask article of the help center](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

If you want to configure something about the device, is almost certainly an acceptable question for the site. If it's about whenever someone considers the device advanced/esoteric enough to be enterprise-grade... not so much.